# WebDriver:: getText() fetches only partial String

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to read the below html code using getText() {Selenium-WebDriver}, this is my locator and script line

```
@FindBy(xpath="//p[@class='radiobutton']") WebElement groupMsg;
System.out.println("This is the group message"+groupMsg.getText()); //msg display on console
```

o/p on console :: This is the group messageRadio button 'Male' is checked

As i showed its showing only "Sex : Male". not getting the "Age group: 5 - 15". Its happening because of 
 (i think Pl correct me if i am wrong)

```
<p class="groupradiobutton">
Sex : Male
<br>
Age group: 5 - 15
</p>
```

Can any one give solution for this?

Comment: what is the locator you have used and i can see there is a <br> tag getting opened. Where its getting ended?

Comment: Please provide locator and java code you used in your script.

Comment: what you tried? please share your code

Comment: there is no way it could just print only first part of the text. `getText()` function doesn't understand `<br>` tag.

Answer (score 4):

Below code is workig.

```
String a=driver.findElement(By.className("groupradiobutton")).getText();
System.out.Println(a);
```

This is printing the output as below in console.

```
Sex : Male
Age group: 5 - 15
```

I have tested with the html you have given.

Comment: you are right, `getText()` function doesn't understand `br` tag, so it must print everything.

Comment: thx Sai. it you are right. looks like i am using wrong class name hence its displaying wrong message.

Comment: @GaurangShah :: Agree getText() wont bother about br tag. it prints the text as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//p[@class='groupradiobutton')).getText();
```